# Why isn't CLion checking for MISRA?

Tags: c, clion, static-analysis, misra, clang-tidy

I want to run the MISRA checks on my code and when I click "Inspect Code" it shows only Clang-Tidy even though I have checked the MISRA setting in the Inspections menu.

[Inspections menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eXfNs.png)
And this are the results of the Analysis.
[Analysis results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiywG.png)
No MISRA. How can I enable them?